# Changing co-ordinate system

Tags: math, geometry, c++-cli, gdi+, gdi

[image]
<sub>(source: [roughnotebook at sites.google.com](https://sites.google.com/site/roughnotebook/Home/axis.png))</sub>

I need to switch from the XY co-ordinate system shown above to the X'Y' co-ordinate system using System::Drawing::Drawing2D (i.e. GDI+). This is what I have in mind:

```
float rotation =                    // +90 below is because AB is the new vertical...
    Math::Atan2(pB.Y - pA.Y, pB.X - pA.X) * 180.0 / Math::PI + 90.0f;

Matrix m;
m.Translate(pA.X, pA.Y);
m.Rotate(rotation);
m.Invert();

array<PointF> points = gcnew array<PointF>{ pC };
m.TransformPoints(points);
```

Is there a way to do this while minimizing rounding errors? Can I avoid the `Atan2` (or other inverse trigonometric function) call here?

Comment: @Rowland, do you see the image now?

Comment: I can now -- What scale of rounding errors are you seeing?

Comment: Nothing great. I haven't yet looked at the actual values. But when I zoom in on some corners, neighboring rectangles show a small overlap or gaps between them. IMHO, this can be minimized by changing or avoiding the rotation calculation.

Comment: This might be an artefact of how you're rendering? I've seen similar in geographical information systems, where two polygons share an edge, but due to the algorithms used for rounding when rendering diagonal lines, small gaps show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with gdi+, but in principle you can do this without inverse trig or operator inversion. (I say "operator inversion" instead of "matrix inversion" because this `Matrix` doesn't look like a matrix to me.)

First, you should be able to avoid the matrix inversion by changing the way you define the operator. Here's a blind stab at it:

```
Matrix m;
m.Rotate(-rotation);
m.Translate(-pA.X, -pA.Y);
```

Now for the rotation itself, the usual way to do it is with a matrix that looks like this:

```
cos(theta)  -sin(theta)
sin(theta)   cos(theta)
```

and you're calculating theta using atan(y/x). But if what you want are the sin and cos, you can just normalize x and y and use them directly:

```
x  -y
y   x
```

No atan needed. *In fact, no trig at all!*

Comment: I assume you mean normalize (pB-pA), not normalize x and y.

Comment: @Beta, But normalizing x and y is indirect trig, isn't it?

Comment: @Vulcan: No; if `v=(pB-pA)`, just divide `v.x` and `v.y` by the length of v (`v.length = sqrt(v.x^2 + v.y^2)`)

Comment: @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft: yes, I spoke carelessly, I should have said something like "normalize (pB-pA)" or "normalize `[x y]`".

Comment: Thanks. Answer accepted. However, I am replacing the trig functions with a square root operation (calculating the length) which is equally expensive. Is it possible to avoid the square root?

Comment: @Vulcan Eager: No. If (pB-pA) is, say, [1 1], then when you transform a simple point like [0 1] the result will involve square roots. You really can't get around it.