# Aligning Matlab CVST's 3D stereo co-ordinate system along local vertical and local horizontal

Tags: image-processing, geometry, linear-algebra, video-processing, matlab-cvst

Using stereo vision [Computer Vision System Toolbox by Mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/products/computer-vision/), I am able to reconstruct the object under inspection.

After calibration, I know the co-ordinate system which stereo setup uses is mentioned [here](http://in.mathworks.com/help/vision/gs/coordinate-systems.html?refresh=true) (it is wrt optical centre of Camera 1).

I have noticed that the same co-ordinate system may not be followed in real world 3D. For example, the local vertical (of a place, which can be found using a spirit level) need not align with the vertical axis (y-axis) of my stereo setup's co-ordinate system.

Suppose I move my object only along the local vertical, without any change in its x position (i.e. local horizontal of that place), according to the stereo co-ordinate system used by the cameras, my object would have moved along y axis (obviously), and also along the x-axis of camera (which is not right, since according to the real world, my object hasn't been moved along local horizontal at all!).

How can I tackle this issue? I am aligning the stereo setup according to the local vertical and local horizontal (using a spirit level), as well as my object. Still, when I move it along local vertical only, there is a few mm change in x-coordinate reading as well. Any inputs regarding this would be appreciated.

Comment: I think its a similar issue as asked by [Agnel Kurian here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147335/changing-co-ordinate-system). Mine is MATLAB and also a 3D co-ordinate system.  The co-ordinate system considered by my Camera1 is different compared to the real world's. For example, the y-axis of Stereo Camera1 isnt the same as (not parallel to) the local vertical.

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind that in the camera-based coordinates the X-Y plane is the image plane, which is inside the camera. It may well not be precisely aligned with the camera's outer casing.

If you need a world coordinate system not tied to the camera, then you can define one by placing a checkerboard in your scene. You can then use the extrinsics function to compute the transformation from the checkerboard's coordinates into the camera's coordinates.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this. I want to know a little more details regarding what to do, what transformation to apply. I want a world co-ordinate system which I define by maybe a checkerboard. How can I define it?